# how to do an auto increment of id inside of class?

Tags: flutter

I am making a todo app with notifications and am using flutter local notifications plugin, How do I generate a unique integer as id for a specific todo so that I can also cancel notification of that specific todo using that unique integer. and the value f the integer must be an int which and the first value must be 0 and then it increment by one .
i used

```
    class data {
        final String name = "test" ;
        final notificationId = UniqueKey().hashCode;

     }
```

but it gives random values and in my case i need values starts from 0 and increment by 1 .How to do it ? is there any others packages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `Shared Preference` to store last int value and increase it on next notification, i hope that will help you.
If you are using `local database` to store notification, then create a column of int type with auto increments, and use that id to cancel that notification

For your reference read here about [Shared Preference](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences)

Answer (score -1):

To generate a unique ID without collision you can with this code

```dart
import 'package:id_gen/id_gen_helpers.dart';

final todoId = genUuid;    // string
final todoId = genTimeId;  // integer
```

Dart package: https://pub.dev/packages/id_gen

If you want to generate auto-increment IDs, try the class `TransitIdGen`:

```dart
final todoId = genTransitId;  // integer
```